# How is the visual studio developer command prompt able to execute executables that are not mentioned in the environment variables?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

Take for example the InstallUtil.exe. How is it possible that I am able to execute this command while the path to it is not in my environment variables?

Path to InstallUtil.exe is: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
This path is not even in my environment variables.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the code within `VsDevCmd.bat`, most likely located at `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools"` The variables you've shown in the GUI are those available all of the time, the ones you're seeing in your cmd.exe session are local to that session, and not transferred outside of it.

Comment: @Compo Okay, it seems that it creates some temporary environment variables. But who calls the VsDevCmd.bat? When does it happen?

Comment: When you select `Tools` **>** `Command Line` **>** `Developer Command Prompt` from the Visual Studio Toolbar Menu